# sinatraでmysqlを使うと "database configuration does not specify adapter"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

質問します。
下記のエラーについて、解らず困っています。

環境フレームワーク：sinatra
操作：Activerecord
DB:mysql

【database.yml】

```yml
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sinatra
    host: localhost
    username: user_1
    password: user_1
    encoding: utf8
```

【bundle exec ruby をするファイルの内容】

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'
require 'sinatra'

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML.load_file('./database.yml')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
end

get '/topics.json' do
  content_type :json, :charset => 'utf-8'
  topics = Topic.order("pass").limit(1)

  status 202
end
```

【エラー内容】

```
/Documents/sinatra/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'

/Documents/sinatra/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'from a.rb:7:in `<main>'

/Documents/sinatra/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:182:in 
`spec': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

【データベースの中身】

```sql
mysql> select * from user;
+--------+--------+
| id     | pass   |
+--------+--------+
| user_1 | user_1 |
+--------+--------+
```

このエラーは具体的に何が問題で起こっているのでしょうか？
調べたのですが、railsの説明しか見当たらず困っています。
呼び出す項目として、passとありますが取り敢えずデータの取得を目標としていますのでお気になさらないでいただきたいです。

雑な説明で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')

の部分を

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
```

に変更するか、ActiveRecord::Base.configurationsを使わずに

```
config = YAML.load_file('./database.yml')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config['development'])
```

でどうでしょうか。